# How to connect Spark SQL to remote Hive metastore (via thrift protocol) with no hive-site.xml?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm using HiveContext with SparkSQL and I'm trying to connect to a remote Hive metastore, the only way to set the hive metastore is through including the hive-site.xml on the classpath (or copying it to /etc/spark/conf/).

Is there a way to set this parameter programmatically in a java code without including the hive-site.xml ? If so what is the Spark configuration to use ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For Spark 1.x, you can set with :

```java
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://METASTORE:9083");
            
final SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc);
```

Or

```java
final SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc);
hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://METASTORE:9083");
```

**Update  If your Hive is Kerberized** :

Try setting these before creating the HiveContext :

```java
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.sasl.enabled", "true");
System.setProperty("hive.security.authorization.enabled", "false");
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.kerberos.principal", hivePrincipal);
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.execute.setugi", "true");
```

Comment: In case of a Kerberized remote Hive cluster what are the additional HiveContext config setting needed? The above code doesn't work for me in this case and I'm wondering if you have a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Still doesn't work. My settings: ("hive.metastore.uris","myValue")
("login.user","myValue")
("keytab.file", "myValue")
("sun.security.krb5.debug","false")
("java.security.krb5.conf","myValue")
("java.library.path","myValue")
("hadoop.home.dir","myValue")
("hadoop.security.authentication","kerberos")
("hive.metastore.sasl.enabled", "true")
("hive.security.authorization.enabled", "false")
("hive.metastore.kerberos.principal", "myValue")
("hive.metastore.execute.setugi", "true")

Comment: Looks to me my local Spark is not even attempting to connect the remote Hive based on what I see in the log

Answer (score 30):

In spark 2.0.+ it should look something like that:

> Don't forget to replace the "hive.metastore.uris" with yours. This
>   assume that you have a hive metastore service started already (not a
>   hiveserver).

```java
 val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("interfacing spark sql to hive metastore without configuration file")
          .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083") // replace with your hivemetastore service's thrift url
          .enableHiveSupport() // don't forget to enable hive support
          .getOrCreate()

        import spark.implicits._
        import spark.sql
        // create an arbitrary frame
        val frame = Seq(("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3)).toDF("word", "count")
        // see the frame created
        frame.show()
        /**
         * +-----+-----+
         * | word|count|
         * +-----+-----+
         * |  one|    1|
         * |  two|    2|
         * |three|    3|
         * +-----+-----+
         */
        // write the frame
        frame.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("t4")
```

Comment: If I provide *configurations* using above `config(..)` method while simultaneously also providing `hive-site.xml`, which one would persist? Is there a way to control that?

Comment: Both. `hive-site.xml` is used as the base configuration that is overriden by Spark properties. The recommended way of mine would be to keep configuration outside the code (in `conf/hive-site.xml`) so there's no need to recompile the app for any configuration changes.

Answer (score 7):

I too faced same problem, but resolved. Just follow this steps in Spark 2.0 Version

**Step1:** Copy hive-site.xml file from Hive conf folder to spark conf.
[image]

**Step 2:** edit spark-env.sh file and configure your mysql driver. (If you are using Mysql as a hive metastore.)
[image]

Or add MySQL drivers to Maven/SBT (If using those)

**Step3:** When you are creating spark session add enableHiveSupport()

> val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("testing")**.enableHiveSupport()**.getOrCreate()

**Sample code:**

```
package sparkSQL

/**
  * Created by venuk on 7/12/16.
  */

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object hivetable {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("hivetable").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

    spark.sql("create table hivetab (name string, age int, location string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile")
    spark.sql("load data local inpath '/home/hadoop/Desktop/asl' into table hivetab").show()
    val x = spark.sql("select * from hivetab")
    x.write.saveAsTable("hivetab")
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Isn't `x.write.saveAsTable("hivetab")` redundant? You already wrote the values via `load data local inpath`

Comment: What version of Hive , hadoop and Spark did you use? Can you specify it exactly? i'm trying to connect but facing issues

Comment: is `spark` not communicating to hive metastore via thrift protocol? why would it need mysql driver?

Comment: I have no idea why spark needs to be able to connect to the hive metastore standalone backend db, but that's what got it to work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the similar questions are marked as duplicate, this is to connect to Hive from Spark without using `hive.metastore.uris` or separate thrift server(9083) and not copying hive-site.xml to the SPARK_CONF_DIR.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("hive-check")
  .config(
    "spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL",
    "JDBC_CONNECT_STRING"
  )
  .config(
    "spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName",
    "org.postgresql.Driver"
  )
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
  .config("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", "JDBC_USER")
  .config("spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", "JDBC_PASSWORD")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
spark.catalog.listDatabases.show(false)
```

Answer (score 5):

I observed one strange behavior while trying connecting to hive metastore from spark without using hive-site.xml.

Everything works fine When we use `hive.metastore.uris` property within spark code while creating SparkSession.
But if we don't specify in code but specify while using `spark-shell` or `spark-submit` with `--conf` flag it will not work.

It will throw a warning as shown below and it will not connect to remote metastore.

```
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: hive.metastore.uris
```

One workaround for this is to use below property.

```
spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris
```

Answer (score 4):

Spark Version : 2.0.2

Hive Version : 1.2.1

Below Java code worked for me to connect to Hive metastore from Spark:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class SparkHiveTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                  .builder()
                  .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
                  .config("spark.master", "local")
                  .config("hive.metastore.uris",                
                   "thrift://abc123.com:9083")
                  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/apps/hive/warehouse")
                  .enableHiveSupport()
                  .getOrCreate();

        spark.sql("SELECT * FROM default.survey_data limit 5").show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! if you are trying to revive one old question, why not trying with some unanswered question instead of one with already a high ranked answer? Salutes!

Answer (score 4):

For Spark 3.x:

```scala
// Scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SaveMode, SparkSession}

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hive_warehouse_hdfs_path")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

```py
# Python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hive_warehouse_hdfs_path") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Check databases available with:

```
spark.catalog.listDatabases().show()
```

[source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html)

Answer (score 2):

Below code worked for me. We can ignore the config of `hive.metastore.uris` for local metastore, spark will create hive objects in spare-warehouse directory locally.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

object spark_hive_support1 
{
  def main (args: Array[String]) 
   {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("yarn")
      .appName("Test Hive Support")
      //.config("hive.metastore.uris", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore")
      .enableHiveSupport
      .getOrCreate();

    import spark.implicits._

    val testdf = Seq(("Word1", 1), ("Word4", 4), ("Word8", 8)).toDF;
    testdf.show;
    testdf.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("WordCount");
  }
}
```

Comment: `hive.metastore.uris` should be given a `thrift://` address, not `jdbc:`

Answer (score 1):

In Hadoop 3 Spark and Hive catalogs are separated so:

For **spark-shell** (it comes with `.enableHiveSupport()` by default) just try:

```
pyspark-shell --conf spark.hadoop.metastore.catalog.default=hive
```

For **spark-submit** job create you spark session like this:

```
SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

then add this conf on your spark-submit command:

```
--conf spark.hadoop.metastore.catalog.default=hive
```

But for ORC table(and more generally internal table) it is recommended to use HiveWareHouse Connector.

Answer (score 1):

Setting spark.hadoop.metastore.catalog.default=hive worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting following error with Spark 2.4.8 Or Spark 3.1.3 or Spark 3.2.2. The hadoop version is 3.2, Hbase 2.4.14 and Hive 3.1.13 and Scala 2.12

**Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot create a record reader because of a previous error. Please look at the previous logs lines from the task's full log for more details.
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:253)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
I am calling spark-submit as follows.**

```
export HBASE_JAR_FILES="/usr/local/hbase/lib/hbase-unsafe-4.1.1.jar,/usr/local/hbase/lib/hbase-common-2.4.14.jar,/usr/local/hbase/lib/hbase-client-2.4.14.jar,/usr/local/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-2.4.14.jar,/usr/local/hbase/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar,/usr/local/hbase/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar" 


/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master local[*] --deploy-mode client --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 480m --driver-memory 512m --driver-class-path $(echo $HBASE_JAR_FILES | tr ',' ':') --jars "$HBASE_JAR_FILES" --files /usr/local/hive/conf/hive-site.xml --conf "spark.hadoop.metastore.catalog.default=hive" --files /usr/local/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml --class com.hbase.dynamodb.migration.HbaseToDynamoDbSparkMain --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=256m" /home/hadoop/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/HbaseToDynamoDb-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

The code is as follows.


val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("Hbase To DynamoDb migration demo")
      .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
      .config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://localhost:9083")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()


    spark.catalog.listDatabases().show()
   val sqlDF = spark.sql("select rowkey, office_address, office_phone, name, personal_phone from hvcontacts")



sqlDF.show()
```

The hive external table was created on top of Hbase as follows.

```
create external table if not exists hvcontacts (rowkey STRING, office_address STRING, office_phone STRING, name STRING, personal_phone STRING) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('hbase.columns.mapping' = ':key,Office:Address,Office:Phone,Personal:name,Personal:Phone') TBLPROPERTIES ('hbase.table.name' = 'Contacts');
```

The metastore is in mysql and I can query tbls table to verify the external table in hive. Is there anyone else facing similar issue?

NOTE: I am not using hive spark connector here.

Comment: This is the known bug reported at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-24706. It seems the functionality has been broken in Spark 3.x. It works fine with Spark 2.4.x and Scala 2.11.

Comment: The issue has been fixed as per https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/31147 pull request but not in offical release yet.