# Why there are many spark-warehouse folders got created?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, jdbc, hive

I have installed hadoop 2.8.1 on ubuntu and then installed spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7 on it. I used spark-shell and created the tables. Again I used beeline and created tables. I have observed that there are three different folders got created named spark-warehouse as :

1- spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-warehouse

2- spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-warehouse

3- spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/sbin/spark-warehouse

What is exactly spark-warehouse and why are these created many times?
Sometimes my spark shell and beeline shows different databases and tables and sometimes it show same. I am not getting what is happening?

Further, I did not installed hive but still I am able to use beeline and also I can access the databases though java program. How the hive came on my machine?
Please help me. I am new to spark and installed it by online tutorials.

Below is the java code I was using to connect apache spark though JDBC:

```
 private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://10.171.0.117:10000/default", "", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to remote hive server from spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997224/how-to-connect-to-remote-hive-server-from-spark)

Comment: Suggestion: Use a fully setup Hadoop installation environment like Hortonworks Sandbox or Cloudera Quickstart for HDFS+YARN+Hive+Spark

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is exactly spark-warehouse and why are these created many times?

Unless configured otherwise, Spark will create an internal Derby database named `metastore_db` with a `derby.log`. Looks like you've not changed that.

[This is the default behavior, as point out in the Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables)

> *When not configured by the `hive-site.xml`, the context automatically creates `metastore_db` in the current directory and creates a directory configured by `spark.sql.warehouse.dir`, which defaults to the directory `spark-warehouse` in the current directory that the Spark application is started*

> Sometimes my spark shell and beeline shows different databases and tables and sometimes it show same

You're starting those commands in those different folders, so what you see is only confined to the current working directory.

> I used beeline and created tables... How the hive came on my machine?

It didn't. You're probably connecting to the either the [Spark Thrift Server](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbcodbc-server), which is fully compatible with HiveServer2 protocol, the Derby database, as mentioned, or, you actually do have a HiveServer2 instance sitting at `10.171.0.117`

Anyways, the JDBC connection is not required here. You can use `SparkSession.sql` function directly.

Comment: I tried using the below codes w/o jdbc but it does not show me the tables which are there in the db. Can you please provide me details here on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833210/can-beeline-and-spark-shell-show-different-databases-for-same-apache-spark)
The below java code shows 0 tables available..

Comment: SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
                .master("local")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file://home/user/Desktop/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-warehouse")
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();
        spark.sql("Show tables").show();

Comment: Well what does `cd $SPARK_HOME/spark-warehouse && beeline -u jdbc:hive2://10.171.0.117:10000/default -e "show tables"` give you?

Comment: spark-warehouse folder shows three database i.e. db1 db2 and default + tab1; same is shown at beeline by "show tables". I mean show databases and show tables. I am not able to execute above command.

Comment: How about `spark.sql("Show databases")`?

Comment: The above code through java shows only 'default' database 
 and through spark-shell it shows all three db1 db2 default.. Can we continue on personnel mails if u feel comfortable? (b.ajinkya1@gmail.com)

Comment: Where did you launch spark-shell? Apparently not within `/home/user/Desktop/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/`

Comment: Yes, I launched it from the above location..Is there any problem due to this? Why doesn't it show in java program?

Comment: Not sure. Start by clearing out all the remnant warehouse directories. Then run the Java program to see where it makes it, and then get `spark-sql` command to connect to that

Comment: Okay thank for ur time.. I will try. I the ans u said that I have configured derby. Does this mean that I'm no more able to process big data?

Comment: You don't have Hive or Hadoop configured. The default Spark package is using a Derby database, not a remote metastore like Postegres or MySQL... That is a whole separate problem. Yes, you can process "big data", but anything that fits in memory or on your single computer is not "big" in today's sense

Comment: Anyways, if you carefully read the documentation, you'll see how Hive integration actually works, and why folders are created where they are... http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: Looking at your code, I think the issue is should be `file:///home` (3 slashes). You missed the root folder

Comment: It does not seem easy to get.  I thought since I installed hadoop before spark so it will do the job. Since I am wrong I will need to start from the beginning. I will try in fully set up environment as u advice.

Comment: Use of three slashes also give one database but not three.

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to just read the data from Apache spark through java and use it for my purpose by storing it somewhere or use spark sql on this data.

Comment: https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/setting-up-a-spark-development-environment-with-java/

Answer (score 1):

In standalone mode, Spark will create the metastore in the directory
from where it was launched.
This is explained here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

So you should set `spark.sql.warehouse.dir`, or simply make sure you always start your spark job from the same directory
(run `bin/spark` instead of `cd bin ; ./spark`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two cents, if you are using `hive` to execute sql from command line, the `spark-warehouse` is also created at the launching directory.

In this situation, you need to specify `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` under `$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml`.

Relaunch hive `metastore` service and the hive warehouse is changed, the `spark-warehouse` won't be created anymore.

Comment: `hive` is deprecated. Please use `beeline`