# Can beeline and spark-shell show different databases for same apache spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, jdbc, hive

I have installed hadoop 2.8.1 on ubuntu and then installed spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7 on it. 
Firstly when I created database through spark-shell and tryied to access it through java JDBC program I was seing no table exists. Then I used beeline and observed that the databases do not exists here too. I created databases through beeline. Why does spark-shell and beeline show different DBs?

They probably should show the same. I tried the plain JDBC program which connects hive2 and fetched the tables and observed that sometimes it show tables I creatd through spark-shell and sometimes shows that of created through beeline...Please help. The same is happening sometimes with beeline too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because your Spark installation 
is not configured properly to access your Hive warehouse.

In such case, Spark-SQL is designed to setup its own local warehouse
and revert to standalone mode. This is intended to ease adoption
for non-Hive users.

To troubleshoot this, you should:

1. Refer to the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables).
2. read the logs and look for anything related to 'hive' or 'metastore' to 
   understand what happens
3. make sure that Spark has access to the hive-site.xml configuration file.
   You can for instance set up a symlink (be sure to check the paths first)

   ```
   ln -s /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml    /etc/spark/conf/hive-site.xml
   ```
4. make sure that your Spark installation has access to the Hive jars 
   (check `$SPARK_HOME/lib`)
5. make sure you have enabled Hive support with something like this:

   ```
   SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am new to spark so sorry for silly questions. I didn't install hive and I do not find hive-site.xml in spark folder. I also don't have any hive folder in my file system. Can you please help?

Comment: Can you please also help me here on [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819568/why-there-are-many-spark-warehouse-folders-got-created)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your setup, then. If you didn't install hive, how can you use beeline? To use beeline, you are supposed to connect it to a HiveServer2 url, which one is it? 
If you only want to try spark-sql in a sandbox environment, you can try this docker: https://github.com/FurcyPin/docker-hive-spark
It sets up a Hive Metastore, a Spark ThriftServer (HiveServer2) and opens a spark-sql shell connected to it. You can also look at the DockerFile to get starting installing a similar environment.

Comment: 'jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default' is my url. I am still not finding hive-site.xml anywhere..Any guess?

Comment: hive-site.xml is a configuration file that allows a Hive client like spark to connect to a HiveServer2. You have to create and edit it yourself. Did you set up a HiveServer2 or a spark ThriftServer?  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2
https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/spark-sql-thrift-server-example/
If you want to get started with Hive and Spark, I would recommend starting with a Hortonworks or Cloudera sandbox to have a preconfigured environment. If you are really new to Hive and Spark, don't use beeline, stick for spark-sql.

Comment: @Furry `beeline` is in `$SPARK_HOME/bin`

Comment: @FurryMachine No I did not set up hiveserver2. I guess thriftServer is set up automatically while installing spark. I will take a pre configured environment directly. Btw, do u have any hive-site.xml with u for demo?

Comment: To use beeline, you have to start the Spark Thriftserver like explained here:
https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/spark-sql-thrift-server-example/
Otherwise, just start spark-sql.
You can find an example of hive-site.xml here, but you don't need it if you only use spark and didn't install hive.
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/test/resources/data/conf/hive-site.xml

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to just read the data from Apache spark through java and use it for my purpose by storing it somewhere or use spark sql on this data.