# Python - Spark - HiveContext - Can't find tables

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive

I'm using a VM with Spark 1.6.0 and I'm tryin to create a dataframe with dat from Hive.

I've 2 tables in default databases but when I'm trying to show all the tables using Spark I don't get any results:

```
sqlContext.sql("show tables").collect()
[]
sqlContext.sql("show databases").collect()
[Row(result=u'default')]
```

My Hive tables was created directly on Hive on Default database:

```
CREATE TABLE team
(id INT, sports STRING, players INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LOCATION "/user/cloudera/data/sports";
```

Why I cannot see my table?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using `HiveContext`?

Comment: yes, Spark creates HiveContext as sqlContext

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997224/how-to-connect-to-remote-hive-server-from-spark

Comment: could you try `sqlContext.sql("show tables in default").show()`

Comment: @GaurangShah it retuns "Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@2dd31aac, see the next exception for details."

Comment: if you running this from shell could you run using `sudo` if possible and check.

Answer (score 1):

you should copy hive-site.xml file to spark conf directory.