# Not able to connect to Hive from Spark-Sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I am trying to connect to Hive using Spark-SQL, but its not able to read tables from hive.

Spark Version : 2.4.0

Am trying to connect to table that is in default Database in Hive. But its throwing below error.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'vasanth' not found in database 'default';
```

Below are details from Hive and Spark.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hive
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
WARNING: Hive CLI is deprecated and migration to Beeline is recommended.
hive> show databases;
OK
default
vsp
Time taken: 0.839 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> show tables;
OK
vasanth
Time taken: 0.081 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> desc formatted vasanth;
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment             

name                    string                                      

# Detailed Table Information         
Database:               default                  
Owner:                  cloudera                 
CreateTime:             Wed Apr 03 13:19:57 PDT 2019     
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN                  
Protect Mode:           None                     
Retention:              0                        
Location:               hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/vasanth  
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE            
Table Parameters:        
    transient_lastDdlTime   1554322797          

# Storage Information        
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe   
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat     
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat   
Compressed:             No                       
Num Buckets:            -1                       
Bucket Columns:         []                       
Sort Columns:           []                       
Storage Desc Params:         
    serialization.format    1                   
Time taken: 0.451 seconds, Fetched: 26 row(s)
hive>
```

```
scala> sc
res7: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@5c7a699b

scala> spark
res8: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@6b8773c7

scala> hContext
res9: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@2bf3ec4a

scala> sql("select current_database()").show(false)
+------------------+
|current_database()|
+------------------+
|default           |
+------------------+


scala> val vso = hContext.sql("select * from  vasanth")
2019-04-04 19:26:04 WARN  ObjectStore:568 - Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: vasanth; line 1 pos 15
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:733)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:685)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:715)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:708)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:708)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:654)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'vasanth' not found in database 'default';
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(HiveClient.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(HiveClient.scala:81)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient$class.getTable(HiveClient.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.getTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.getRawTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:118)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:700)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:700)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.getTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:699)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.getTable(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.lookupRelation(SessionCatalog.scala:701)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:730)
  ... 92 more
```

I expected the table to be read using Spark-SQL, but not sure why its throwing object not found error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to remote hive server from spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997224/how-to-connect-to-remote-hive-server-from-spark)

Comment: possible issue with hive-site.xml. Spark is using another hive-site.xml or can't find any.