# Unable to run spark sql through shell script

Tags: shell, spark-shell

I am unable to query a table in spark through shell script. But if i am running through command line, i am able to get the result. Problem arises when i insert those command in shell and trying to run.

Created a shell script :

```
vi test.sh
```

Inserted below spark shell command

spark-shell

```
val results =sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from table_name ")

results.show()
```

It is entering into spark shell but not running the  below two command

`val results =sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from table_name ")`

`results.show()`

Comment: did you register the table before running the SQL command?

Comment: The table is available in the DB....while running my actual query i gaveDB.table_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Except](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) to get spark-shell working in bash script.

OR create a file with .scala and copy all your spark commands there.

```
val results =sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from table_name ")

results.show()

System.exit(0)
```

use ' spark-shell -i script_name.scala ' to run your script in bash or directly on linux terminal.

System.exit(0)----- to get out from spark-shell

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are able to query the data using hive. You need to do the configuration so that spark sql can work with HDFS and hive. Execute the following step for establishing a connection between spark and hive.

Create the file hive-site.xml at location $SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml. Make the following entry in this file (change the value to point to the metastore server of your hive installation):

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <!--Make sure that <value> points to the Hive Metastore URI in your cluster -->
    <value>thrift://sandbox.hortonworks.com:9083</value>
    <description>URI for client to contact metastore server</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

The following links give more detail on this:

[How to connect to remote hive server from spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997224/how-to-connect-to-remote-hive-server-from-spark)

https://acadgild.com/blog/how-to-access-hive-tables-to-spark-sql

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing as a shell script, you can write as a scala file and run the scala file.

file.scala

```
val results =sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from table_name ")

results.show()
```

spark-shell -i file.scala