# Unknown Host Error when running sql query over remote hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I could not find anything on this after hours of Google search so I hope I can get some ideas to my problem here.

I am trying to get data from a remote hive cluster using spark2. I have followed:

1. [How to connect to a Hive metastore programmatically in SparkSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980584/how-to-connect-to-a-hive-metastore-programmatically-in-sparksql)
2. [How to connect to remote hive server from spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997224/how-to-connect-to-remote-hive-server-from-spark)

And I was able to connect to the remote hive metastore successfully.

However, my problem starts when I execute a query in the remote hive. e.g spark.sql("select count(*) from table"). I will get an "unknown host: ns-bigdata" error. Where ns-bigdata is the cluster name of the remote cluster.

What other things am I missing here? Need I specify where the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir should be as well? e.g. hdfs://local-cluster:8020/user/hive/warehouse

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like your DNS server is not working. Try using IP addresses

Comment: Don't think it's the DNS as my spark session is able to connect to the remote hive metastore with the hostname i.e spark.config("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uri", "thrift://remote.hive.domain:9083").

Comment: That's just a string. The connection is not attempted until you actually run a query

Comment: Try running simpler query spark.sql("show databases").show() to make sure the connection is fine. If this works fine, include database name also in the query. spark.sql("select count(*) from database.table")

Also, to be clear the machine you are running spark2-submit or spark2-shell is not present in the cluster "ns-bigdata".

Comment: After some thinking I think @cricket_007 may be right. Think when I try to run a query, hive is trying to access the warehouse directory in hdfs to check the schema but could not find where it is because my spark cluster doesn't know where ns-bigdata is. I'll try to see if I can get the IP of ns-bigdata and try to put in in my host file of my cluster.

Comment: found out the PIC did not configure cross realm authentication in Kerberos. which is why we can't connect to the hive thrift server with spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason was the customer did not set their kerberos cert in the hive thrift server for cross realm authentication. We ended up using jdbc impala.

Answer (score 0):

The hive server URL is in the hive site. Can you try and use that??
Also do check if hive-site.xml is present in the conf/ directory of spark