# Hive table requires 'repair' for every new partitions while inserting parquet files using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have spark conf as:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")    
sparkConf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
sparkConf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
```

I am using the spark context to write the parquet files into hdfs location as:

```
df.write.partitionBy('asofdate').mode('append').parquet('parquet_path')
```

In hdfs location, the parquet files are stored as 'asofdate' but in hive table I have to do '**MSCK REPAIR TABLE <tbl_name>**' everyday. I am looking for a solution on how I can do **recover table** for every new partitions using spark script (or at the time of partition creation itself).

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you [integrate hive with spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997224/how-to-connect-to-remote-hive-server-from-spark) to make your job easier.

After the hive-spark integration setup, you can enable hive support while creating SparkSession.

```
  spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Now you can access hive tables from spark.
You can run repair command from spark itself.

```
spark.sql("MSCK REPAIR TABLE <tbl_name>")
```

I would suggest to write dataframe directly as a hive table instead of writing it to parquet and do repair table.

```
df.write.partitionBy("<partition_column>").mode("append").format("parquet").saveAsTable("<table>")
```

Comment: I have streaming service that generates 100> parquet files every 1 hour. So, it might be overhead running repair table every hour. And I need to save parquet files to the hdfs location too.