# Connecting Spark from my local machine to a remote HiveServer

Tags: apache-spark, hive

How can I connect Spark from my local machine in Eclipse to a remote HiveServer?

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of the `hive-site.xml` from the remote server, and add it to `$SPARK_HOME/conf`

Then, assuming Spark2, you need to use `SparkSession.enableHiveSupport()` method, and any `spark.sql()` queries should be able to communicate with Hive.

Also see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362864/2308683)