# Spark submit: Table or view not found using jar

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

When I run `HiveRead.java` from intellij ide I can successfully run and get result. Then I created jar file ( It's a maven project ) , then I tried to run from IDE, it gave me

```
ClassLoaderResolver for class "" gave error on creation : {1}
```

Then I looked at SO answers and found I had to add datanulcues jars, I did something like this

```
java -jar /home/saurab/sparkProjects/spark_hive/target/myJar-jar-with-dependencies.jar --jars jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/home/saurab/hadoopec/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar
```

Then I got this error

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Persistence process has been specified to use a ClassLoaderResolver of name "datanucleus" yet this has not been found by the DataNucleus plugin mechanism. Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.
```

Somewhere I found I should do `spark-submit`. So I did like this

```
./bin/spark-submit --class HiveRead --master yarn  --jars jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/home/saurab/hadoopec/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar --files /home/saurab/hadoopec/spark/conf/hive-site.xml /home/saurab/sparkProjects/spark_hive/target/myJar-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Now I get new type of error

```
Table or view not found: `bigmart`.`o_sales`;
```

HELP ME !! :)

I have copied my `hive-site.xml` to `/spark/conf`, started hive-metastore service ( `hiveserver2 --service metastore` )

Here is [HiveRead.Java code](https://pastebin.com/L7FSg4X6) if anyone is interested.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980584/how-to-connect-to-a-hive-metastore-programmatically-in-sparksql

Comment: @undefined_variable I have done everything that is said on that question

Comment: I add `--files /spark/conf/hive-site.xml` at last and it ran , but now I cannot access tables in my bigmart database.

Answer (score 0):

Spark session is not able to read the hive directory.

Provide the hive-site.xml file path with spark-submit command as below.

For hortonworks - file path /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml

pass it as --files /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml in spark-submit command.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please consider using the code notation for your code in the answer above.