# How can I read from different Hive Metastore using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

```
val spark=
SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://10.30.61.13:9083")
        .appName("Spark Hive Example")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate()
    val df=spark.table("xtable")
    df.show()
```

Through this I need to set this in hive-sit-xml . So when I want to connect to another hive then again I need to change the hive-site.xml.So how can I generalise it

Comment: Why do you need to change hive site? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980584/how-to-connect-to-a-hive-metastore-programmatically-in-sparksql

Comment: that means no need to change hive site right ?

Comment: I've used that code successfully.