# Configure Hive metastore in my local Spark shell

Tags: apache-spark, hive-metastore

I need to configure Hive metastore for use with Spark SQL in spark-shell.

I copied my `hive-site.xml` to spark/conf folder - it didn't work.

Then tried in spark shell

```
spark.conf.set("hive.metastore.uris","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","hive")
```

But got an error:

```
scala> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","hive")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot modify the value of a static config: spark.sql.catalogImplementation;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig.requireNonStaticConf(RuntimeConfig.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig.set(RuntimeConfig.scala:41)
  ... 49 elided
```

Tried opening spark shell using

```
spark-shell --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive hive.metastore.uris=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

still not able to read

Error:

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from car_test.car_data_table").show
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `car_test`.`car_data_table`
```

Hive metastore is not getting attached to spark sql.

My hive-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/user/raptor/tmp/hive/warehouse/</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>HIVE_USER</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>HIVE_PASSWORD</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

spark-env.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/Softwares/jdk1.8.0_221/
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.1.1
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/user/Softwares/hadoop-2.7.3/
export HIVE_HOME=/home/user/Softwares/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.1.1
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop
#SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib
export SPARK_HOME=/home/user/Softwares/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop-2.7-scala-2.12
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=${SPARK_HOME}/conf
export SPARK_LOG_DIR=${SPARK_HOME}/logs
```

Comment: Hive metastore and database that stores Hive metadata are two different things. https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-hive-metastore.html

Answer (score 0):

Got help from this post.

[How to connect Spark SQL to remote Hive metastore (via thrift protocol) with no hive-site.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980584/how-to-connect-spark-sql-to-remote-hive-metastore-via-thrift-protocol-with-no)

And One another thing, Spark 2.* will only support hive metastores from hive 0.12.0 to hive 1.2.0. I was using hive 2.1.1 that was the issue.