# How to configure Apache Spark 2.4.5 to connect to MySQL metastore of HIVE?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive-metastore

I am trying to run a Hive query using `HiveContext` object and receiving the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError   
Traceback (most recent call last) 
/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o864.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager(SharedState.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$2.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$2.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager(SessionCatalog.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.isTemporaryTable(SessionCatalog.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.isRunningDirectlyOnFiles(Analyzer.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:681)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:713)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:706)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:706)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:652)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    ... 90 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-3bcaf444213a> in <module>
----> 1 df = sqlCtx.sql("select * from emp_master.emp_global")

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    356         [Row(f1=1, f2=u'row1'), Row(f1=2, f2=u'row2'), Row(f1=3, f2=u'row3')]
    357         """
--> 358         return self.sparkSession.sql(sqlQuery)
    359 
    360     @since(1.0)

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    765         [Row(f1=1, f2=u'row1'), Row(f1=2, f2=u'row2'), Row(f1=3, f2=u'row3')]
    766         """
--> 767         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    768 
    769     @since(2.0)

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'
```

I have placed the `hive-site.xml` file in the `$SPARK_HOME/conf` directory. Is there a step that I'm missing? Looking for some light into this error. I have a MySQL metastore for Hive, and it works perfect while running queries through Hive shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect Spark SQL to remote Hive metastore (via thrift protocol) with no hive-site.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980584/how-to-connect-spark-sql-to-remote-hive-metastore-via-thrift-protocol-with-no)

Comment: @mazaneicha Had seen that question already. Couldn't get information about starting metastore server and hiveserver2 from there, which were the steps I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure hive mysql metastore to work with spark, copy the `hive-site.xml` from `$HIVE_HOME/conf` directory to `$SPARK_HOME/conf` directory and add the following property to the file.

```
<property>
   <name>hive.metastore.uri</name>
   <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
</property>
```

This enables external applications to interact with hive through thrift server.

Then, start hive metastore server and hiveserver2 by issuing the following commands.

```
hive —-service metastore
hive —-service hiveserver2
```

Now, you should be able to access hive from spark.