# pyspark pip installation hive-site.xml

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have installed pyspark using (pipenv install pyspark) and type pyspark after activating 'pipenv shell'
I can able to open pyspark terminal and able to run few spark code.
but I am trying to figure out to enable Hive (for that where I need to place hive-site.xml (with mysql metastore properties) and not able to see any spark/config folder in order to place hive-site.xml).

Unfortunately the existing application much relied on Pipefile (so i have to follow pipenv install pyspark)

Comment: Check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980584/how-to-connect-spark-sql-to-remote-hive-metastore-via-thrift-protocol-with-no?